# Xcode won't use with FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME

Tags: xcode, flutter

Xcode won't build using $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME) or $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)

Runner -> Target -> Build Settings -> Versioning

[image: Runner -> Target -> Build Settings -> Versioning]

Runner -> Target -> General -> Identity

[image]

Runner -> Flutter -> Generated.xcconfig

[image]

info.plist

[image]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? The Generated.xcconfig correctly has the version information from my pub spec.yaml version: 1.0.3+5

But each time I build the version information is null.

Comment: Where do you see version information as null?

Comment: In app it reports it as null+null via package_info. And if I GetInfo from Finder on the build it reports a '--'. If I set the version values myself package_info reports correctly.

Comment: Also, at some point I had to add Runner -> Project -> User-Defined -> FLUTTER_ROOT to build, which would indicate that it is not puling it from Generated.xcconfig either

Comment: Do you have any other xcconfig file in the project? If you do... do they include `Generated.xcconfig`?

Comment: There is a folder called Flutter that contains Release.xcconfig, Debug.xcconfig, Generated.xcconfig, and AppFrameworkInfo.plist, all of which is generated/managed by Flutter. The 3rd screenshot is of data inside the Generated.xcconfig

Comment: `Release.xcconfig` and  `Debug.xcconfig` include `Generated.xcconfig`, right?

Comment: Yes, both files #include Generated.xcconfig as the last line

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue yesterday and really struggled to find out what's going on my flutter project. I hope my two cents help anyone out there...

One day I manually updated version in xcode (super mistake) then Generated.xcconfig not worked anymore. I still don't know why some settings have changed also but anyway here's solution:

well-working versioning project:

[image: xcode screenshot with no problem]

project of the problem:

[image: xcode screenshot with problem]

When I changed the three Runner configuration file to `Debug`, `Release`, `Release`, the version showed up immediately:

[image]

ps) I got hint from the chat of @Zholen and @Claudio Redi. Thank you so much. I still don't know which action triggered that settings but I'm going to bed now..

Comment: thanks man, worked a treat!

Comment: when I followed these steps and ran `flutter build ipa --obfuscate --split-debug-info debug-info` I saw that `Project base configurations detected, removing.` which led to the same error. This GH issue helped me resolve my problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57567

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the version of your app, just change in pubspec.yml

like version: 1.0.4+3

Then run

“flutter run”

--- or ---

"fvm flutter run" if you are managing your flutter version using fvm

This will regenerate ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig and the same referred in Info.ptlist file

FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME=1.0.4

FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER=3

Make sure the version details not hard-coded in the file  ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj. If it is hardcoded , you can simply remove or comment it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Now I solved it. The key point is that when /ios/Flutter/Generated.xconfig exists, the Flutter builder will not rebuild it. However, you can just **delete** Generated.xconfig, and the Flutter builder will **rebuild** it with the version setting in pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME), $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)
The values ​​of the above two parameters is come from file `Generated.xcconfig`, this file will auto generate.

All you need to do, is set your scheme related to this file.

[related Generated config to your scheme configurations, just like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41juX.png)

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue after hours of pain.